# PHP array to tree

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, tree, converters

I have an array with values like these:

```
array (
   array(a, a, a),
   array(a, a, b),
   array(a, b, a),
   array(b, c, d)
)
```

I would like to convert this array to a tree with associative arrays, like this:

```
array (
    a => array (
        a => array(a, b),
        b => array(a)
    ),
    b => array (
        c => array(d)
    )
)
```

I am trying to solve this problem for hours. Do anyone know a solution for this problem? The values of the first array are coming from mysql database and they are ordered.

Comment: you've already answered your question. Your "would like" structure is exactly what you need to build in PHP. If you learn the basic concepts of how multi-dimensional arrays are built/accessed in PHP, this will become a trivial problem.

Comment: If depth is not given this thing is actually interesting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two levels :

```
 $a = array (
       array(a, a, a),
       array(a, a, b),
       array(a, b, a),
       array(b, c, d)
    );

    $out = array();
    foreach ($a as $row) {
        $out[$row[0]][$row[1]][] = $row[2];
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($out);
```

//http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tcb-fwz

**EDIT:**
Using the max depth based on the length of the array:

```
$input = array(
array('a', 'a', 'a', 'z'),
array('a', 'a', 'c', 'z'),
array('a', 'a', 'a', 'y'),
);

$result = array();

foreach ($input as $row) {

    for ($i = count($row)-1; $i >=0; $i--) {
        if (!isset($work)) {
            $work = array($row[$i]); //last item
        }else{
            $work = array($row[$i]=>$work);
        }
    }

    $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $work);
    unset($work);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

// at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1ag-4cj

If the $input array elements are arrays with different lengths, there will be problems.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it would be better if I could specify the depth of the array. I mean I will need to use this for more arrays like the one in my question, so it would be the best to make this dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($initial_array as $row) {
    $result[$row[0]][$row[1]][] = $row[2];
}
```

Code can be changed easily so it will work for any depth of your resulting tree.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it would be better if I could specify the depth of the array. I mean I will need to use this for more arrays like the one in my question, so it would be the best to make this dynamic.